# Replace background images with single image and get the same effect

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I used to scale an image into a size of a column using `background-image` but as I realized that background images won't allow `alt` tags I need to change it to just an `img` tag,

Using `background-image`

```
     <div style=" background-image: url('test.jpg'); " class=" img-chess wpb_column column_container vc_column_container col no-extra-padding instance-3" data-using-bg="true" data-shadow="none" data-border-radius="none" data-border-animation=""data-border-animation-delay="" data-border-width="none" 
data-border-style="solid" data-border-color="" 
data-bg-cover="true" data-padding-pos="all" data-has-bg-color="false" 
data-bg-color="" data-bg-opacity="1" data-hover-bg="" data-hover-bg-opacity="1" data-animation="" data-delay="0">
        <div class="vc_column-inner">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">   
    <div class="wpb_raw_code wpb_content_element wpb_raw_html">
        <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        </div></div></div> </div></div>

.full-width-content.vc_row-fluid .wpb_column {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover
}
```

How to do the above using an `img` tag?
Are there any easy ways to achieve this using css and html?

thanks

Comment: Show us what you have tried. Create a jsfiddle or post your code here that so that we may understand better what it is you are trying to accomplish. From what you have written, I'm fairly certain its possible, I just need that example so I can understand where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper and then have your content and your image inside that wrapper. You can then make the image be positioned absolute inside that content and then place it wherever you want. You just have to make the parent be position relatively and it will work. Here is an example:

https://jsfiddle.net/u2xnwfct/

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  padding-left: 30px;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  /*below 2 lines will make sure it stays centered regardless of the height of the parent.*/
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <h1>This is my title</h1>
    <img src="https://www.gdrc.psychol.cam.ac.uk/images/apple/image" alt="My Image"/>
</div>
```

Comment: @NaveenDINUSHKA I would not like to share my email. What part are you not understanding?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited the code to explain a bit better

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Might have not been very clear with my question here but if anybody get to this post and wonder what the right answer is,

```
.img-class{
height:100px or whatever the amount you need here //in my case this is the padding used for the column
object-fit:cover;
object-position:center center;
}
```

This  video helped me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kmVrFwkI9Fw